# Python group by one column and calculate percentage of another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    Frame   SizeOfExposure
0    1         5
1    1         5
2    2         7
3    3         2
4    3         8
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage of `SizeOfExposure` for each row group by `Frame` number.

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby("Frame")["SizeOfExposure"].sum()
```

This prints the sum of SizeOfExposure for each frame.  However, when I tried

```
df['SizeOfExpPerc']=df["SizeOfExposure"]/df.groupby("Frame")["SizeOfExposure"].sum()
```

I am getting 'Nan' filled for most rows. How do I calculate?  The desired output is

```
    Frame   SizeOfExposure  SizeOfExpPerc
0    1         5                  0.5
1    1         5                  0.5
2    2         7                  1.0
3    3         2                  0.2
4    3         8                  0.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original DataFrame filled by aggregated values, so possible division:

```
df['SizeOfExpPerc']=df["SizeOfExposure"]/df.groupby("Frame")["SizeOfExposure"].transform('sum')
print (df)
   Frame  SizeOfExposure  SizeOfExpPerc
0      1               5            0.5
1      1               5            0.5
2      2               7            1.0
3      3               2            0.2
4      3               8            0.8
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby("Frame")["SizeOfExposure"].transform('sum'))
0    10
1    10
2     7
3    10
4    10
Name: SizeOfExposure, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

The method by @jezrael is probably more efficient, but here is an alternative solution using `groupby` and `apply`.

```
>>> df.assign(SizeOfExpPerc=df.groupby('Frame')['SizeOfExposure'].apply(
        lambda group: group / group.sum()))
   Frame  SizeOfExposure  SizeOfExpPerc
0      1               5            0.5
1      1               5            0.5
2      2               7            1.0
3      3               2            0.2
4      3               8            0.8
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it depends of data mainly. `np.random.seed(123)

N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Frame': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'SizeOfExposure':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})
df = df.sort_values(['Frame','SizeOfExposure']).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: `%timeit df['SizeOfExpPerc']=df["SizeOfExposure"]/df.groupby("Frame")["SizeOfExposure"].transform('sum')
64.8 ms ± 2.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

`%timeit df.assign(SizeOfExpPerc=df.groupby('Frame')['SizeOfExposure'].apply(lambda group: group / group.sum())) 
360 ms ± 4.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`